# Negative areas after polygonize in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, gdal-polygonize

I have been trying to convert this raster data using QGIS's Polygonize function: https://daac.ornl.gov/VEGETATION/guides/Decadal_LULC_India.html

The converted geopackage is returning many geometries with negative areas. So much so that the data is highly inaccurate, and some categories are having negative areas with x^10 sq. meters in magnitude.

The features basically resemble the ones I found in this stack overflow answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/243707/161470 , where the holes are located outside the geometry and are larger than the geometry itself.

I wanted to know if the error had to do with the quality of data or the size of data we are trying to polygonize?

Comment: It is invalid to have a hole outside the polygon. Decide if they are real polygons and convert to multipolygons  or delete them

Comment: There are thousands of such polygons and it isn't possible for me to individually correct all of them.

Comment: then it seems as if you have not carried out the polygonize function correctly